# EF 6 table mapping error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm running into an error trying to save some data in my MVC app. We're using code first.

I'm saving my data like this:

```
var fieldDefinition = db.CustomFields
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.CustomFieldId == thisResp.CustomFieldId);
var newData = new CustomData
{
    ProjectId = new Guid("280288D7-7630-E511-8420-00215E466552"),
    CustomFieldId = thisResp.CustomFieldId
};
if (fieldDefinition.AllowMultiple)
{
    var values = thisResp.Value.Split(',');
    foreach (var thisValue in values)
    {
        var newMulti = new CustomDataMulti
        {
            CustomDataId = newData.CustomDataId,
            CustomValue = thisValue
        };
        db.CustomDataMulti.Add(newMulti);
    }
}

db.CustomData.Add(newData);
db.SaveChanges();
```

However, I get this message:

> Unable to determine the principal end of the 'PublicationSystem.Model.CustomData_CustomDataMultis' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.

My classes are set up like this:

```
public partial class CustomData : BaseEntity
{

    [Key]
    public int CustomDataId { get; set; }
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomFieldId { get; set; }
    //...
    public virtual ICollection<CustomDataText> CustomDataTexts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CustomDataMulti> CustomDataMultis { get; set; }
}
```

CustomDataMapping.cs

```
public CustomDataMapping()
{
    //Primary key
    HasKey(t => t.CustomDataId);
    //Constraints 
    Property(e => e.CustomValue).IsUnicode(false);
    HasMany(e => e.CustomDataTexts)
        .WithRequired(e => e.CustomData)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    HasMany(e => e.CustomDataMultis)
        .WithRequired(e => e.CustomData)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    ToTable("CustomData");
}
```

CustomDataMulti.cs

```
[Table("CustomDataMulti")]
public partial class CustomDataMulti : BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomDataMultiId { get; set; }

    public int CustomDataId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string CustomValue { get; set; }

    public virtual CustomData CustomData { get; set; }
}
```

CustomDataMultiMapping.cs

```
public CustomDataMultiMapping()
{
    //Primary key
    HasKey(t => t.CustomDataMultiId);

    //Constraints 
    Property(e => e.CustomValue).IsUnicode(false);

    ToTable("CustomDataMulti");
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EntityFramework doesnt understand the principal end of the relationship between the following entities :-

CustomData and CustomDataMulti.

This is because the relationship between the two entities must have one side of the relationship that's constant.

In this case, A **CustomData** entity can have multiple **CustomDataMulti** objects. (List).

But can a **CustomDataMulti** ever exist without belonging to a **CustomData** object?

What you need to do is change the CustomDataMulti class so that the virtual property for **CustomData** is Required.

See Below :-

```
[Table("CustomDataMulti")]
public partial class CustomDataMulti : BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomDataMultiId { get; set; }

    public int CustomDataId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string CustomValue { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual CustomData CustomData { get; set; }
}
```

This is the convention that EntityFramework Uses to determine relationships.

To give a clearer example.

Think of an **OrderItem**, An **OrderItem** would always belong to an **Order**.

An **OrderItem** without a relevant Order is useless.

The **Order** entity is the **prinicpal** end of the relationship.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Should I set CustomDataId = newData.CustomDataId or CustomData = newData ?

Comment: You can set both, but CustomDataId = newData.CustomDataId will be suffice

Comment: I appreciate your explanation. That is helpful. I ended up doing the CustomData = newData since CustomData was now required and I would get an error otherwise.